# How to disable the rows of a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview and i want to disable the rows of the gridview and let the footerrow enabled.

The rows are bineded to database. So the number of rows is not predefined (always changing).

Thank you

Comment: I'll guess that the gridview you defined is using `AutoGenerateColumns = "true"`, so you have no real access to the columns in the designer. If you don;t need the role column exclude it from the select statement, or use a `<asp:TemplateColumn>` for all your column definitions, and you can set 'Visible = "False"` for any individual column.

Comment: @kOe to be clear, do you want to disable _all_ the rows? And what do you mean by "disable" exactly anyway? By default the rows are not editable or deletable, unless you include buttons for that. Please show your existing gridview code, and also explain a bit more clearly what you want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @ADyson i mean by disable to make it not possible to edit for a specific user.

Comment: Well for that then you would need to a) determine the identity of the current user, b) determine their permissions, c) use that result to decide whether to show/hide the column with the edit button - that's assuming you want to disable all the rows at once. Or should a decision be made per-row? It's still not clear.